# Running nosetests for pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, nose, nosetests

How would one run unit tests with `nose` for Apache Spark applications written in Python?

With `nose` one would usually just call the command

```
nosetests
```

to run the tests in the `tests` directory of a Python package. Pyspark scripts need to be run with the `spark-submit` command instead of the usual Python-executable to enable the import of the `pyspark`-module. How would I combine `nosetests` with `pyspark` to run tests for my Spark application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps we use nosetest to test [sparkling pandas](https://github.com/holdenk/sparklingpandas). We do a bit of magic in our utils file to add pyspark to the path based on the SPARK_HOME shell environment variable.

Comment: That certainly sounds interesting. Would you care to be a bit more specific about what needs to be done to run your tests? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, the run-tests script we put in the repo just checks to make sure that the SPARK_HOME enviroment is set, and if it is it calls nosetests with a bunch of optional flags. We also added a base test case that we extend for our individual tests which starts and stops a local spark context. This works because we add the things to our python path in the utils file I mentioned which is probably what your tests are missing.

Comment: Thank you, with the help of your code I was indeed able to get my unit tests running! @Holden

Comment: @karlson: Maybe you could put an example in a gist or something?